# Optimization in vehicle routing problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, vehicle-routing-problem

I have a problem with the thesis. Photos attached. We have 126 orders and 1 collection point. And we have 4 machines to do this. When it is solved, our routes are not optimal.

Is there a way to optimize?

The problem is implemented, but this is not the optimal path.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]